# How to decode INE/IFE mexican passport data

Tags: decode, decoding, pdf417

I am looking a way to decode raw binary data written in PDF417 barcode at the backside of mexican passport card (aka IFE/INE).

I've read the data from PDF417 code using scanner software and I got this

```
0000  31 64 30 8b d6 5f c8 2e  4d 95 8c 97 31 cf 23 36  | 1d0~~_~.M~~~1~#6 |
0010  f4 1b 42 8b 55 ba 14 cd  42 a8 8f c3 01 5c b1 ab  | ~~B~U~~~B~~~~\~~ |
0020  06 c3 d2 55 31 9f 6c 7d  ba 9c 9a 60 ad 07 65 c1  | ~~~U1~l}~~~`~~e~ |
0030  92 28 32 66 48 43 2f 94  3c 28 34 d3 41 31 42 99  | ~(2fHC/~<(4~A1B~ |
0040  70 47 a6 73 70 61 c0 58  3c a2 9c 0e 31 90 ca 16  | pG~spa~X<~~~1~~~ |
0050  22 47 22 b0 22 44 2f ae  b0 5e b6 cf 34 7f 4a 6a  | "G"~"D/~~^~~4~Jj |
0060  a6 7d 0e 72 10 cc 51 e0  7d 78 f1 7e bc db a9 fc  | ~}~r~~Q~}x~~~~~~ |
0070  51 6e 3c 39 5c 52 72 09  ed 1c ce b0 2b f0 aa 9a  | Qn<9\Rr~~~~~+~~~ |
0080  5b 70 53 89 84 5e b1 ce  ae 5f d1 ea 6c 7f ea 76  | [pS~~^~~~_~~l~~v |
0090  6d e3 84 83 f3 7d df 23  37 ef 58 d2 ae 21 e0 ae  | m~~~~}~#7~X~~!~~ |
00a0  d6 2b 86 9f 58 db 7c 55  5e 72 7a 34 56 b1 0e 62  | ~+~~X~|U^rz4V~~b |
00b0  6f 20 9a a9 32 02 9b 5c  0a 71 c3 12 76 b1 08 10  | o ~~2~~\~q~~v~~~ |
00c0  53 37 fc bf a2 d2 2c 2b  7b 6a d2 42 c0 44 ed 45  | S7~~~~,+{j~B~D~E |
00d0  e0 a5 82 48 41 b9 7a 7a  96 7d 95 44 fd 27 66 6d  | ~~~HA~zz~}~D~'fm |
00e0  c5 ed 7b b5 f6 ae 06 5a  0e e2 cb c8 c5 52 3b 98  | ~~{~~~~Z~~~~~R;~ |
00f0  71 d2 ac f2 c3 33 be d7  1f 8e 49 6e e7 4d 6e 3d  | q~~~~3~~~~In~Mn= |
0100  86 1d 94 33 e3 05 14 d4  d3 ff b7 3a 9f 8a ea 7a  | ~~~3~~~~~~~:~~~z |
0110  d3 7e a5 87 ea 43 8b 6e  36 54 49 5a cc 02 83 66  | ~~~~~C~n6TIZ~~~f |
0120  57 1c 27 5e 5f e1 d0 c8  8d da cb 98 8e 36 a5 33  | W~'^_~~~~~~~~6~3 |
0130  0b 56 74 82 4b e2 d4 ae  c5 e4 1d e9 16 c7 ac b6  | ~Vt~K~~~~~~~~~~~ |
0140  a8 9a fb 4b ed 30 d3 9f  6a 45 8e e1 87 b5 96 3e  | ~~~K~0~~jE~~~~~> |
0150  31 25 45 f4 c6 74 32 48  fd 95 bd ff 61 4c c3 07  | 1%E~~t2H~~~~aL~~ |
0160  b2 22 9d 0b 54 5d 55 7c  eb 3b 61 b8 b7 5c 1d bc  | ~"~~T]U|~;a~~\~~ |
0170  06 45 94 28 c8 e6 5a 43  15 4f 35 2a 63 0e ea ce  | ~E~(~~ZC~O5*c~~~ |
0180  8d f3 49 2b 56 95 76 6e  7c 3a 8e c8 3d 41 37 a7  | ~~I+V~vn|:~~=A7~ |
0190  5b 7e 13 b8 e2 22 6b 9b  71 e1 cc f6 f0 a8 08 9e  | [~~~~"k~q~~~~~~~ |
01a0  2c cc 0d ec f7 98 79 84  d0 92 78 6a 4a ec 15 42  | ,~~~~~y~~~xjJ~~B |
01b0  e0 70 87 26 21 21 e7 2e  65 b0 fb b3 83 d3 73 4a  | ~p~&!!~.e~~~~~sJ |
01c0  13 a8 99 79 1e 5e cb fa  73 d1 eb 33 82 3f 1e d9  | ~~~y~^~~s~~3~?~~ |
01d0  24 7f b3 30 30 37                                 | $~~007           |
```

Every card gives different data, but total length is the same and begin marker "1d0" and end marker "007" are always the same.

Do you know an algoritm to decode this data? Thanks.

Comment: @danny I guess this will be a digital copy of human-readable data written on the card. So yes, it is a legal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as the INE that information is encrypted, if you need to access the data, you need to contact the goverment institution to request the public key.

Check [PDF](http://portalanterior.ine.mx/archivos3/portal/historico/recursos/IFE-v2/DS/DS-GacetasElectorales/2014/gaceta-150/GE_150_021.pdf.pdf) page 23: